# Was looking for a network graphing library which loads a network graph in real-time

Tags: javascript, graphs

I have a 200,000 node network graph which I want to load on a webpage. I was looking at viable libraries and found sigmajs which looks good.

Now my question is - Is there a library through which I can dynamically load only a portion of the graph?. In the sense, can I only load, let's say 100 nodes and interconnections and the user can scroll through the graph displayed on an HTML canvas. The website shouldn't fetch all 200K nodes at once, but only fetch and display the 100 nodes which the user is viewing. The graph does not change at the server-side, 200K nodes and interconnections are fixed.

Is there any such library or can I do this with sigmajs?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is impossible to do in js, because browsers can not handle this mass of objects. It might be possible by some server-side support (pre-processing data on the server-side and sending only a visible/reduced part to the browsers).